# webdriver.PhantomJS sending EOF to stdin

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am having a possibly really stupid problem in Python 3.4. Every time I initialise an instance of PhantomJS from code and then try to get user input.

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()     #nothing even loaded yet
login = input('Login: ')

---
Login: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webdriver_and_input.py", line 10, in <module>
    login = input('Login: ')
EOFError  #no description here
```

This simply does not work even if I add `browser.quit()` between the lines. `browser` still for some reason sends an EOF to stdin (`browser.quit()` does not kill the process itself, but this is a different story)

When opening a python shell, right after I execute `browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()` the input in the shell itself becomes laggy, for example, if I try to scroll through commands history with up button I get something like

```
>>> browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()[[A[A
```

Could someone explain why this happens and how to prevent Selenium from tampering with i/o operations this way? I had no problem with `raw_input` in the same situation in Python 2.7.

I am on Linux Mint 17.1, Selenium is 2.53.2, PhantomJS is 2.1.1 (installed via npm).